# OAuth2 Access Token format

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

Trying to find information about this. I'm wondering what format the OAuth2 Access Token is, or should be. Is it ok to use JWT format for the Access Token?

Comment: I am not sure about the answer but what I do know to be very bad is if one could generate a access token by formatting userinfo in JWT. So at least make sure you prevent that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OAuth does not specify the access token itself, the format is opaque to the protocol flow. It can be any thing you want, e.g. a JWT if you want it to be self-contained.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any guidelines for this? I am asking because I first thought about using JWT as it is a "standard", but now I'm wondering if it is unnecessary...

Comment: here's some guidance: http://nimbusds.com/blog/implementing-oauth-2-0-access-tokens/ in the end it is up to the agreement between RS and AS, which does not necessarily need to be standardized

Comment: that link's dead, do you have any others to that content, Hans?